# mPDF Open Sans font cannot render some german letters

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, mpdf

I am trying to generate PDF with the german word **"möchte"** (the letter **ö** is the issue here)..
using the font that I added(Open Sans) in `/ttfonts` folder and set it on `config_fonts.php`..

```
"open_sans" => array(
    'B' => "OpenSans-Bold.ttf",
    'BI' => "OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf",
    'EB' => "OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf",
    'EBI' => "OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf",
    'I' => "OpenSans-Italic.ttf",
    'L' => "OpenSans-Light.ttf",
    'LI' => "OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf",
    'R' => "OpenSans-Regular.ttf",
    'SB' => "OpenSans-Semibold.ttf",
    'SBI' => "OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf",
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
        'useKashida' => 75,
    )
```

I also read https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-6-x.html and tried modifying `config_lang2fonts.php` .. I even set it everything to `open_sans`

```
$unifont = "open_sans";
return array($coreSuitable ,$unifont);
```

PS: The font file Open Sans I downloaded is already no subsetting.

But the output is still not like as I expected, it shows:
[image]

PHP

`$mpdf = new mPDF('','A4','','open_sans' , 30 , 12 , 12 , 12 , 10 , 10);`

Mark Up

```
@font-face{
font-family:open_sans;
src: url('mypath/mpdf60/ttfonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf');
}
```

---

I tried using the default fonts of mPDF like **dejavusans**, It works perfectly. But what I need is Open Sans. Did I miss a configuration in mPDF or what? What is the problem?

Comment: have you set the encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: Yes Sir, characters like **Ü** works. Only **ö, ä and ü** are not working. Weird isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you see a regular `o` followed by an unknown character strongly suggests the second character is a single non-spacing diaeresis, not available in the font you are using.

Checking the character sets of DejaVu Sans and Open Sans proves my hunch is right. DejaVu Sans *does* contain a 'COMBINING DIAERESIS' `U+0308: ¨`. OpenSans does *not*.

Use Unicode Normalization on your input text to replace the sequence `o+¨` with its composite character `ö` `U+00F6`. The same goes for `ä` `U+00E4` and `ü` `O+00FC`.